# Why does a Windows Domain have two names?

Tags: domain-controller, windows, domain-name

I am working at corporate headquarters called Papermash. I joined their domain on my Win7 Pro, what I found interesting is that I could login to the domain using credentials PAPERMASH\username, and also PAPERMASHCORPORATE.com\username. When I tried to visit papermashcorporate.com using my browser there was no such website, if I ping it all packets fail. This is quite confusing for me, could someone explain what is going on here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PAPERMASH is the NetBIOS name of the domain.

PAPERMASHCORPORATE.com is the DNS name of the domain.

You can also log on using your UPN (User Principal Name) in the format: user@PAPERMASHCORPORATE.com

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc739093(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Great response! Is there a reason that packets cannot be sent or received to the DNS name of the domain, even though it has a public IP address? Perhaps it is a special type of server that does not have ports to the internet?

Comment: That depends on a lot.  Unless its also hosting a website it wont respond to http requests, and unless its configured to respond to ICMP packets it wont respond to ping requests.  Your network/firewall may also be such that you cannot receive ping replies from that host.

Answer (score 0):

Still, nobody is legally required to have a website on a registered domain name, and some old schoolers still believe that the website should be at www.papermashcorporate.com and that a web browser should not be redirected from papermashcorporate.com to the www.papertiredoftypingthis.com server, since it is basically slightly unclean (your servers are no longer only at leaves of your dns hierarchy).

Comment: Very helpful response. For the record papermash and papermashcorporate are fabrications of my imagination, but the issue is now resolved thanks to these answers.